Java lambda not able to access inner scope?
Consider this class:
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class c
{
    static interface a<T> extends Callable<T>
    {
        static <T> a<T> of(Callable<T> method) { return new concreteA(method); }

        int getValue();
    }

    static class concreteA<T> implements a<T>
    {
        private final Callable<T> delegate;
        concreteA(Callable<T> delegate)
        {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public int getValue() { return 99999; }
        public T call() { return this.delegate.call(); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(a.of(() -> getValue()));
    }
}

This complains that getValue() is not defined in c. And I get that. Is there any syntactic sugar that can work around this? Or is this just something that you have to just fall back to anonymous inner classes?

In a case such as this you typically need to use either an anonymous inner class or a concrete implementation of the interface. Java doesn't provide a mechanism for lambdas to automatically inherit or access methods from interfaces they're indirectly implementing.

Just to be clear: you expect the compiler to handle the input to of as if it was an instance of the return type of of, and the input declared before of has run?

@DuncG it certainly can do that in the case of an anonymous class implementation.

@I'L'I I think unless there's something not at all obvious that can square this circle you are probably correct. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.
